# Limits with definite integration

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

$Evaluate:$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x \int_{0}^{x} e^{x^2} dx} {e^{x^2}}$$

*My attempt*

First I dealt with numerator with integral :

As $$\int_{b}^{a} f(x) dx= \int_{b}^{a} f(a+b-x)\,dx$$
To get it as $$\int_{0}^{x} 1\cdot dx =x$$

So the limit turned to be

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac {x^2} {e^{x^2}}=0$$

Is it true?

Comment: Please get your formatting at least somewhat right *before* you post the question.

Comment: Sorry for that. But I am just learning about it recently. So, I may mistake but I am trying it to do it correct.

Comment: Note that the integral in the numerator does not makes sense since your interval of integration depends on the variable you are integrating with respect to. Do you perhaps want $$ \int_0^x e^{t^2}\, dt $$ in the numerator?

Comment: Okay. But in my text book it is given as I have typed. I can give you the picture of it if you want to see.

Comment: It is likely a typo on their side then. In any case, the computation of your integral is wrong. Do you know L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: Yes to get $$lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac {2+2x}{4x^2 +2}$$

Comment: @Sobi Can you tell me why this integral does not count to be correct one? What is the reason behind it?

Comment: @Mark Viola Can you why this integration is wrong? I mean why can not be integrate it? What is reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using L'Hospital's Rule yields

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x\int_0^x e^{t^2}\,dt}{e^{x^2}}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^x e^{t^2}\,dt+xe^{x^2}}{2xe^{x^2}}\\\\
&=\frac12+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^x e^{t^2}\,dt}{2xe^{x^2}}\\\\
&=\frac12+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{x^2}}{2e^{x^2}+4x^2e^{x^2}}\\\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the solution. :)

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Why was this down voted??

Answer (score 2):

By L'Hospital,

$$\frac{\displaystyle\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt}{\dfrac{e^{x^2}}x}\to\frac{e^{x^2}}{\dfrac{(2x^2-1)e^{x^2}}{x^2}}\to\frac{x^2}{2x^2-1}\to\frac12.$$

Comment: Isolating the integral avoids the need for a double application of the rule.