# Definite integral's basic question on definition

Tags: definite-integrals, definition

[Limits with definite integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2912195/526026)

Please see this link and then answer my query.

My question:

Why can't we integrate with the variable like that is given? What is the reason for it? Please explain in simple terms... (A beginner :-))
(Reason for both the question as well as for the attempt)

Comment: The siplest explanation is to avoid confusion.  The limits on the definite integral are specific values of the argument, while the variable of integration is a dummy, where any letter can be used.  For example $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(y)dy$.  If you want $b$ to be $x$, the first form might be confusing, while the second is clear.  This avoids problems when the integral with $x$ as a limit appears inside another expression, where x plays a role.

Comment: Okay. I got the *x* in the $f(x) $ is just a dummy variable. but why the first form creates confusion?  I mean it may be treated as the second form. Just simple. Or is it just the convention to be like that only? Because what we use in the Newton Leibnitz type problems it has some time limits of function such as 0 to $x$ and the integarting function is f(x, t).

Comment: Please feel free to tell me if I am mixing up these two concepts. And about the remedies also. :-)

Comment: My feeling is that you are overthinking the situation.  As long as you can clearly make the distinction between the upper limit argument and the dummy, you won't have any problem.  I have seen confusion when iterated integrals or multiple integrals are used and the limits involve the arguments.  In these cases it is absolutely necessary to use different letters for the dummy.

Comment: Oh. Okay. I think you are right : I am just overthinking. Well, thanks again for helping me. :-)